# Change <a> position to "absolute" on hover (to display full wording)

Tags: css, hover, position, overlap, absolute

Have a set of links in rows.

CSS:

```
.table div {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    width:150px; /*width needs to be fixed, since we're limited in space*/
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden
} 
a.trick,a.trick:link,a.trick:active,a.trick:visited {position:static}
a.trick:hover{position:absolute}
```

HTML:

```
<div class=table>
  <div>Text here</div>
  <div><a class=trick href="#">Text here may be too long to fit</a></div>
  <div>Next column</div>
  <div>of my table made of divs</div>
</div>
```

Works great in Opera and Firefox (on hover overlaps the next "column", displaying full content).

In Chrome (Safari too, likely) does not react to :hover at all.

Anyone knows a way to bypass, preferably without JS/jQ (pure CSS)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to determine on the server the maximum number of characters to allow on the link you could use the following strategy:

CSS:

```
.table div {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    width:150px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden
} 
a.trick span.extendedText,
a.trick:link span.extendedText,
a.trick:active span.extendedText,
a.trick:visited span.extendedText {
    display:none;
}
a.trick:hover span.extendedText{
    display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class=table>
    <div>Text here</div>
    <div><a class=trick href="#">Text here may <span class="extendedText">be too long to fit</span></a></div>
    <div>Next column</div>
    <div>of my table made of divs</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that's a solution, but I don't want to do this math really. but thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd love to click "Useful answer" (tried it), but I need rep to do it hence accept my gratitude with "Thank you", please :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want it to receive position absolute, what that has got to do with the size of the words, etc..

Ok, I saw your example working here http://jsfiddle.net/R6dkJ/ on firefox.

To do this exact thing "correctly", you would for an example do this:

```
a.trick:hover{white-space:nowrap;}
```

This achieves the same effect.

The `absolute` property is used for positioning the element itself. Of course you can use it for hacks like this to get some desired effect - but you will most definitely run into incompatibilities between browsers when you do so.

Comment: Why not? Updated the code - now you can [see](http://jsfiddle.net/FuT7v/2/) how it's supposed to work (works in opera/firefox, but not in chrome)

Comment: I understand what you mean, but i love hacks which are cross-browser and a lot shorter :). P.S. white-space:nowrap won't give anything there. P.P.S. Thanks a lot for participation!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a bit of jQuery, which is:

```
$('.trick').mouseover(function(){$(this).css('position','absolute');});
$('.trick').mouseout(function(){$(this).css('position','relative');});
```

For some reason Chrome/Safari want additional affirmation that position actually should become absolute :).
Now works everywhere (including IEs).

Thanks for participation, and enjoy this nice "hack" :).

Comment: If you are willing to accept a jQuery solution you shouldn't point out you want a CSS only solution and specifically say no JQ or JS lol :P glad you solved your problem anyway.

Comment: I know, but it's still nice :). CSS solution is still welcome, but I think it's Gecko's glitch about position. P.S. I said "preferably", not "only" :).